# Доступ к переопределенным методам

Tags: c#, ооп, function-overloading, override

Есть задача [«OverloadResolutionOverride» (Задача)](https://problembook.net/content/ru/Oop/OverloadResolutionOverride-P.html):

Что выведет следующий код?

```
class Foo
{
  public virtual void Quux(int a)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Foo.Quux(int)");
  }
}

class Bar : Foo
{
  public override void Quux(int a)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Bar.Quux(int)");
  }
  public void Quux(object a)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Bar.Quux(object)");
  }
}

class Baz : Bar
{
  public override void Quux(int a)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Baz.Quux(int)");
  }
  public void Quux<T>(params T[] a)
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Baz.Quux(params T[])");
  }
}

void Main()
{
  new Bar().Quux(42);
  new Baz().Quux(42);
}
```

Данный код выведет:

> `Bar.Quux(object)`
>   `Baz.Quux(params T[])`

[В ответе к этой задаче](https://problembook.net/content/ru/Oop/OverloadResolutionOverride-S.html) указано:

> "Есть такое правило: если при вызове некоторого метода в «текущем» классе находится подходящая сигнатура, то компилятор не будет даже смотреть на родительские классы."

Разве считается, что перегруженный метод `Quux(int)` находится в базовом классе, а не в текущем? И если так и есть, то каким образом мне обратиться именно к методу `Quux(int)` текущего класса?

Comment: код - в вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы вызвать конкретно Quux(int) из Bar или Baz нужно явным образом привести обьект класса к Foo:

```
Foo bar = new Bar();
Foo baz = new Baz();
bar.Quux(42); 
baz.Quux(42);
```

Тогда получим желаемый вывод:

> ```
> Bar.Quux(int)
> Baz.Quux(int)
> ```

Comment: Нет, это совсем другое, что вы делаете. Вы используете объекты класса `Foo` (с *единственным* методом `Quux()`), и так цель задания - *"Который из двух методов применится?"* - потеряется.

Comment: @MarianD Согласен. Но я задал два вопроса. И на один из них я ответ нашел. На первый вопрос есть ответ по ссылке: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734889/access-to-overridden-methods/48735560#48735560

Comment: @salkcid: Целесообразно было бы задавать по _одному_ вопросу в каждом вопросе.

Comment: @salkcid Понял. +1 за ваш ответ.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Quux(object a)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Bar.Quux(object)");
}
```

в классе `Bar` и

```
public void Quux<T>(params T[] a)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Baz.Quux(params T[])");
}
```

в классе `Baz` точно такими методами, как в ответе к этой задаче:

> Eсли при вызове некоторого метода в «текущем» классе находится подходящая сигнатура, то компилятор не будет даже смотреть на родительские классы.

Другие 2 методы, имея `override`, хотят от компилатора смотреть на родительские классы (имеют сигнатуру с декорацией).

Comment: Please, write answer down in english, because i don't understand the way you wrote it in russian

Comment: @salkcid это будет нарушением правил Stack Overflow на русском.